# How to update a record in Linq-To-Sql in Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-8, local-storage

I use below Code To Insert New Item In Cart Database:

```
using (MFTDataContext Cartdb = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString))
                        {
                            Database InsertItemCart = new Database
                            {
                                ProductID = int.Parse(product_id[0]),
                                ProductName = product_name[0],
                                ProductPrice = int.Parse(product_price[0]),
                                ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.Quantity,
                                ProductTotalPrice = product_totalpriceINT,
                                ProductImageURL = product_image[0]
                            };


                            Cartdb.MFTCart.InsertOnSubmit(InsertItemCart);


                          Cartdb.SubmitChanges();
```

Now What code to use to Update the Same Record. Suppose singletonInstance.Quantity is changed from 1 to 5. Now how to update same record. I dont want to create new record. how to update same record

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Update(int itemID, int newQuantityValue)
{
    using (var context = new YouContextType())
    {
        var item = (from item in context.YourEntity
                    where item.ID == itemID
                    select item).Single();

        item.Quantity = newQuantityValue;
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```